# file name in the text box after browsing using usiner form in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

How can I return the file name of an excel file after selecting it using the `browse button` and then the `TextBox` next to the `browse button` should display the file name?

**Here is my Browse button code:**

```
Private Sub inputfilebrowse_Click()

Dim pathString As String
Dim resultWorkbook As Workbook
Dim found As Boolean
fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:= _
             "Excel Workbooks (*.xls*),*.xls*", Title:="Open Database File")

If fileToOpen <> False Then
    MsgBox "Open " & fileToOpen
End If

'---check if it's already opened
'For Each wb In Workbooks
    'If InStr(pathString, wb.Name) > 0 Then
       'Set resultWorkbook = wb
        'found = True
        'Exit For
    'End If
'Next wb
End Sub

Private Sub inputsheetpath_Change()
    fileToOpen.Value = TEinputsheetpath_Change.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean, but try to add line `TEinputsheetpath_Change.Text = fileToOpen` just after `MsgBox "Open " & fileToOpen`. Is it what you need?

Comment: I need whatever the path - fileToopen variable gathers after browsing in the desktop the same has to be reflected in the text area named "inputsheetpath_Change" in the user form

Comment: add line `inputsheetpath.Text = fileToOpen` after `MsgBox "Open " & fileToOpen`

Comment: I have tried adding this line you suggested butting getting run time error 424 - Object required !! Will be able to help me out ???

`If inputfileToOpen <> False Then
    MsgBox "Open " & inputfileToOpen
TEinputsheetpath_Change.Text = inputfileToOpen
End If`

Comment: change `TEinputsheetpath_Change.Text = inputfileToOpen` to `inputsheetpath.Text = inputfileToOpen`

Comment: Thanks @simoco - I need one more help when i click on submit a macro has to be run ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub inputfilebrowse_Click()

Me.inputsheetpath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:= _
             "Excel Workbooks (*.xls*),*.xls*", Title:="Open Database File")
End Sub
```

Comment: If `inputsheetpath` is a `TextBox`, this should work.